# ARM template Key vault access policy to group instead of identity principle

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I went through many `SO`, however didn't find solution to specific problem.

> I have created a Key Vault, all the team members should be able to
>   access this key vault.
>
> This works if I add the group via the portal in the access policies.
>   However, it seems that the when I tried to add it from ARM template it
>   is creating identity principle and team is not able to access key
>   vault.

this is what I tried to give access policies.

```
{
        "tenantId": "----",
        "objectId": "----",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers"
          ]
        }
      }
```

> As I can see there is nothing specific permission to group mentioned explicitly. When I run this ARM template then it is creating access policies with Identity principle category I need to have this category set to Group.
>
> Any ideas how I can map group to access key vault instead of identity principle ?

I checked that object Id are correctly mapped, however I am not sure about the properties. 
[image]

**EDIT**
after deployment we get access policy as compound identity:
[image]

**EDIT 2**
full template:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
  "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
  "name": "[parameters('KeyVaultName')]",
  "location": "*****",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "family": "A",
      "name": "Standard"
    },
    "tenantId": "***********************",
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "tenantId": "***********************",
        "objectId": "***********************",
        "applicationId": "***********************",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Decrypt",
            "Encrypt",
            "UnwrapKey",
            "WrapKey",
            "Verify",
            "Sign",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Set",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "Purge"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "Get",
            "List",
            "Update",
            "Create",
            "Import",
            "Delete",
            "Recover",
            "Backup",
            "Restore",
            "ManageContacts",
            "ManageIssuers",
            "GetIssuers",
            "ListIssuers",
            "SetIssuers",
            "DeleteIssuers",
            "Purge"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "enabledForDeployment": true,
    "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
    "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, make sure you use the correct `tenantId` which your subscription located and `objectId` of your Azure AD ***security*** group.

You can get the `tenantId` in `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `Properties` -> the `Directory ID` is the `tenantId`.

Then in the `Azure Active Directory` -> `Groups` -> search for your security group -> get the `Object Id`.

[image]

My working sample:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaults_joykeyvault1212_name": {
            "defaultValue": "joykeyvault1212",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vaults_joykeyvault1212_name')]",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "family": "A",
                    "name": "standard"
                },
                "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "objectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enabledForDeployment": false,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": false,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please see the edit. I checked that it is correctly mapped. The group which we are pointing is DL list from mailer system

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Also have a test with `Mail enabled security` group, it also works, just use the `Object Id` in your screenshot, it should work.

Comment: Not yet. I cross checked the Object Id and Tenant Id, Both are mapped correctly. I observed one more change  i.e. `"applicationId": "XXXXXXXXXX1",`. I am looking into it

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande What do you mean `mapped correctly`? Do you want to add the group to the access policy of the keyvault with ARM template? If so, why it is related to the application id? Just replace the `tenantId` and `objectId` with your value in the template, then check the `Access policies` of your keyvault in the portal after deployment, will it work?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande On my side, it appears as `Group`, https://i.stack.imgur.com/orVSR.png, could you provide the complete template which  you used to deploy in your question?

Comment: I have added full template in question please check.

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande You don't need to add the `"applicationId": "***********************"`, just remove it. If you add this line with an applicationId of a service principal, it means the service principal on behalf of the group, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-secure-your-key-vault#active-directory-authentication). In your case, you just need to use the `"tenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "objectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",` then the group(i.e. the members in the group) will be able to access the keyvault.

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Could you get it now?

Comment: that's the thing. I am not sure why that `ApplicationId` was there. but it was causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not able to figure it out why it was happening. please edit the answer so other people will be able to get help from it.